# Java Regex Non-Capturing Group

Tags: java, regex

I am having some trouble getting regex to match a string in Java. Here are the strings I want to match: `String Transformation Action` and `Transformation Action`. Basically, if `String` is present, I want to match it, otherwise I would only match the remaining String.

I tried to utilize non-capturing group in regex, however it is not working.

Here is my regex: 
`String regexFilter = "(?:String) (Transformation) (Action)";`. 
This will match `String Transformation Action`, however as soon as I take away `String`, it will not match.

Comment: Read about [quantifiers](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make the `String` part optional by using a `?`:

```
String regexFilter = "(?:String )?(Transformation) (Action)";
```

Also, there isn't much point in putting capturing groups around literal text (e.g. `Transformation` and `Action`) since you always know what those groups will capture.

```
String regexFilter = "(?:String )?Transformation Action";
```

Comment: What if I also want "Action" to be optional too? I tried the same with "Action" and it did not work as well as "String".

Comment: @Froggy Did you try `(?:String )?Transformation(?: Action)?`?

Comment: Ah, I see. I did that except I did put a space between "Transformation" and "Action" group.

Answer (score 1):

Make `String` part optional using this regex:

```
String regexFilter = "\\b(?:String )?Transformation Action\\b";
```

PS: I have also added `\\b` (word boundary) to make your don't match `Transformation Action111`  OR `xyzTransformation Action` type strings.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make the non-capturing group optional. The `?` quantifier means match (`1` or `0` times)

```
String regexFilter = "(?:String )?(Transformation) (Action)";
```